# How to change the font weight globally?

Tags: fonts, xecjk

I used `\setCJKmainfont{Noto Sans CJK TC}` with package `xeCJK` to assign which font I would like to use on Chinese characters. However, the reguler one is too thick to me. How to change the font weight (Noto are offered in 7 weights) to any of the lighter one globally?

Comment: Solution: `\setCJKmainfont{Noto Sans CJK TC Light}`

Comment: If you've solved this issue on your own, you can post it as an answer yourself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in the comments.